# How to dismiss pages

Tags: wear-os

I'm playing around with the wearable SDK and created some additional pages for my sample app.

Is there a convenient way to dismiss / delete a single page by e.g. swiping?

I just found calls for adding, but not for removing (even after an action)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible, because even a multi-page-notification is (from a technical point-of-view) just one single notification which can only disapper in its entirety.

The only possibility I see here is to set a pending intent to a broadcast receiver, figure somehow out on which page the user was when dismissing the notification, and then create a new notification without this page.

Comment: Yes, you could repost the notification without one of the pages, but this is not how the API is intended to be used so please don't do this.

Comment: Mark: Would you mind telling us then, how this can be accomplished then? Or is this particular workflow (deleting a single page) out of scope of the API?